# Unable to take pictures in Xamarin.Forms application

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I am building an android application.
When I deploy this to the emulator and run it, the function of "Take Picture" throws a runtime error that causes the application to get terminated.

The error is `"Unable to get file location. This most likely means that the file provider information is not set in the Android Manifest file."`

Screenshot -
[image: Take Picture]

This is my manifest file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.companyname.singleton">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="31" />
    <application android:label="SingleTon.Android" android:theme="@style/MainTheme">
            <provider android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
          android:authorities="SingleTon.Android.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
                <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                           android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
            </provider>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAPTURE_SECURE_VIDEO_OUTPUT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAPTURE_VIDEO_OUTPUT" />
</manifest>
```

This is my file_paths.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <external-files-path name="my_images" path="Android/data/com.plugin.mediatest/files/Pictures" />
</paths>
```

I have also tried changing the value in the file_paths.xml to

```
<external-files-path name="my_images" path="Pictures" />
```

The screenshot of the project structure looks like this.
[image: Project Structure]

Comment: I think you must put the package name into the `android:authorities` tag, like `android:authorities="com.companyname.singleton.fileprovider"`, also remember to request permission to access camera and storage write on code, sometimes request them on the manifest isn't enough

Comment: @FabriBertani Thank you! I made it work by changing the packagename on the firstline ``package="com.companyname.singleton"`` to ``"Singleton.Android"``